# How can I arrange this DIVs in partial view using bootstrap or Css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm developing an online-store website using *Asp.net MVC 5* and *Razor Engine*. I have a *View* for show products using *Carousel* . I show a small image of products in right of page (GoodDetails.cshtml) and then show more details in `_GoodDetailsAjax.cshtml` .

**GoodDetails.cshtml**

```
<div >
<div class="row">

    <div  class="col-lg-9 col-md-9" id="DivAjax">
        @{Html.RenderAction("GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = Model.GoodDetails.FirstOrDefault().DetailsGoodID });}
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 pull-right center-block" >
        @foreach (var item1 in Model.GoodDetails)
        {
            <div>
                <input type="image" class="img-responsive"  src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item1.DetailsSmallImage1">
            </div>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(@item1.DetailsName, "GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = @item1.DetailsGoodID }, new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "DivAjax",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        })

        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to full screen that div with `InfoDiv` id . How can I do it ? I tried Css and very bootstrap classes  but I couldn't do it .

Thanks in advance .

**_GoodDetailsAjax.cshtml**

```
 <div class="row container">

   @foreach (var item in Model.GoodDetails)
  {

    <div style="height:auto;" class="carousel slide article-slide col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="article-photo-carousel">

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div style="border:1px solid;" class="carousel-inner cont-slider">

            <div class="item active">
                <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage1">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage2">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage3">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12" >
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage1">
            </li>
            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage2">
            </li>
            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage3">
            </li>
            <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage4">
            </li>
        </ol>


        <a style="background:none !important;" class="left carousel-control" href="#article-photo-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a style="background:none !important;" class="right carousel-control" href="#article-photo-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="InfoDiv" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 " >
        <p>@item.DetailsExtraInfo</p>
        <p>@item.DetailsProducer</p>
        <p>@item.DetailsSize</p>

   }
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: you mean, you want to make that `div` with `100%` width? so update your question with CSS code.

Comment: Yes I want to full screen (100%) width that div @jiff I added CSS word to my question , Thank you

Comment: your missing a closing div in your example code ain't you? one is needed below <p>@item.DetailsSize</p>

Comment: No in my project  I have that Div , probably I deleted it mistakenly  when I write this post , Thank you @Seabizkit

Comment: k np. just and FYI in GoodDetails.cshtml you use 9 and 2 which totals 11, bootstrap uses a 12 grid system... PS i know I'm not solving the problem...yet ;-).. just following what you doing.

Comment: k your problem stems from using a grid system and then using "pull right" doesn't make much sense... this is in GoodDetails.cshtml

Comment: Yeah you're right ,That's why I tested every classes for fix it but ... :/ @Seabizkit

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the below code with ajax

```
<div  class="col-lg-9 col-md-9" id="DivAjax">
    @{Html.RenderAction("GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = Model.GoodDetails.FirstOrDefault().DetailsGoodID });}
</div>
```

This `<div>` has `class="col-lg-9 col-md-9"` so your partial view will also renders in the `div` with same class of `class="col-lg-9 col-md-9"`. So this is the reason why your div in partial view is not full width.
You have to update the `row` code with ajax like below

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="DivAjax">
    <div class="row">
        <div  class="col-lg-9 col-md-9" >

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 pull-right center-block" >
            @foreach (var item1 in Model.GoodDetails)
            {
                <div>
                    <input type="image" class="img-responsive"  src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item1.DetailsSmallImage1">
                </div>
                @Ajax.ActionLink(@item1.DetailsName, "GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = @item1.DetailsGoodID }, new AjaxOptions()
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                UpdateTargetId = "DivAjax",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
            })

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the partial view

```
<div class="row container">
   @foreach (var item in Model.GoodDetails)
   {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div style="height:auto;" class="carousel slide article-slide col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="article-photo-carousel">
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div style="border:1px solid;" class="carousel-inner cont-slider">

                    <div class="item active">
                        <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage1">
                    </div>
                    .
                    <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                        <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage4">
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <a style="background:none !important;" class="left carousel-control" href="#article-photo-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a style="background:none !important;" class="right carousel-control" href="#article-photo-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @foreach (var item1 in item)
            {
                <div>
                    <input type="image" class="img-responsive"  src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item1.DetailsSmallImage1">
                </div>
                @Ajax.ActionLink(@item1.DetailsName, "GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = @item1.DetailsGoodID }, new AjaxOptions()
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                UpdateTargetId = "DivAjax",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
            })

            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="InfoDiv" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 " >
            <p>@item.DetailsExtraInfo</p>
            <p>@item.DetailsProducer</p>
            <p>@item.DetailsSize</p>
        </div>
    </div>
   }
 </div>
```

You have to place the ajax form inside the partial view and for that you have to do little customize to your code
hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you , I know that , but I don't know how can I fix it ? because I have another div beside `DivAjax` :/

Comment: i have an idea,  it will update the whole page but will work

Comment: Could you please say me  your idea ?  Thank you

Comment: Thank you a lot , but it didn't show me partial view, If I got it truly that Ajax codes couldn't be in  partial view , am I right ?

Comment: you can. use the ViewBag to send `Model.GoodDetails` to partial file.

Comment: Yes , Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sure , Thank you dear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102967/discussion-between-anand-and-shima-amini).

Answer (score 0):

There is small organisational error in your `_GoodDetailsAjax.cshtml` file as per `Bootstrap`. You have added `col-md-12` after `col-lg-12` which should be other way around.

GoodDetails.cshtml

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

      <div  class="col-md-9 col-lg-9" id="DivAjax">
      <!-- product details starts -->
      @{Html.RenderAction("GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = Model.GoodDetails.FirstOrDefault().DetailsGoodID });}
      <!-- Product details ends -->
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 pull-right center-block" >
          @foreach (var item1 in Model.GoodDetails)
          {
              <div>
                  <input type="image" class="img-responsive"  src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item1.DetailsSmallImage1">
              </div>
              @Ajax.ActionLink(@item1.DetailsName, "GoodDetailsAjax", new { id = @item1.DetailsGoodID }, new AjaxOptions()
          {
              HttpMethod = "GET",
              UpdateTargetId = "DivAjax",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
          })

          }
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_GoodDetailsAjax.cshtml

```
<div class="row">

   @foreach (var item in Model.GoodDetails)
  {

    <div class="carousel slide article-slide" id="article-photo-carousel">

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div style="border:1px solid;" class="carousel-inner cont-slider">

            <div class="item active">
                <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage1">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage2">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage3">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img alt="" title="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsImage4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators text-center" >
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage1">
            </li>
            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage2">
            </li>
            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage3">
            </li>
            <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#article-photo-carousel">
                <img  alt="" src="~/Images/GoodDetails/@item.DetailsSmallImage4">
            </li>
        </ol>


        <a style="background:none !important;" class="left carousel-control" href="#article-photo-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a style="background:none !important;" class="right carousel-control" href="#article-photo-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="InfoDiv" class="" >
        <p>@item.DetailsExtra0nfo</p>
        <p>@item.DetailsProducer</p>
        <p>@item.DetailsSize</p>

   }
   </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dg0n28z5/3/

Hope that make sense.

Comment: Thank you dear , I updated my view according to your code but unfortunately the result is the same :(

Comment: Umm... the code worked for me on fiddle though. Have you fixed the `div`s with class `container` and `row`? they needs to be separate `div`s.

Comment: Yes , I did it , I separated it